# Cutecomm unable to access USB device

Tags: usb, serial-port

Permissions is preventing cutecomm from reading `/dev/ttyUSB0`

```
$ ls -l /dev/tt* | grep -i usb
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188,  0 Dec  3 19:18 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

How can I automate the permissions to ensure that device is readable?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER
```

Reboot may be needed.

Comment: Reboot isn't needed. If the user is logged in, he only needs to log out and in again.